# CGI/Ruby - converting string to an integer

Tags: ruby, cgi

Below is my test.cgi file. The params coming in from the html are:

```
{"FirstNum"=>["3"], "SecondNum"=>["3"]}
```

Why isn't the `a.class` showing up as an integer? I need to do math with the values, and the form sent them as an integers. Even the Ruby `.to_i` doesn't work.

```
#!/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby

require 'cgi'

cgi = CGI.new
puts "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

arr = cgi.params

a = arr['FirstNum']

a.each do |a|
  puts a.class
end
```

Comment: What is the output of `puts a.class`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#class-CGI-label-Parameters):

> The method `params()` returns a hash of all parameters in the request as name/value-list pairs, where the value-list is an Array of one or more values. The CGI object itself also behaves as a hash of parameter names to values, but only returns a single value (as a String) for each parameter name.

So when you say:

```
arr = cgi.params
```

you get a Hash in `arr` whose keys are the CGI parameter names and whose values are arrays of strings; `arr` is a bad name here because it is a Hash, not an Array. That means that this:

```
a = arr['FirstNum']
```

gives you an array of strings in `a`. If you only want one value then use the `[]` method on `cgi` to get a string and then `String#to_i` to get a number:

```
a = cgi['FirstNum'].to_i
```